# Non-existent tablespace when importing MySQL from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, import

I usually export a Drupal database from one instance of phpMyAdmin to another on a different server without any issues but lately I have been getting the error when I import:

```
#3510 - Tablespace my_database doesn't exist.
```

The line of SQL causing the problem is:

```
/*!50100 TABLESPACE `my_database` */ ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I've never encountered tablespaces before and I cannot see where in phpMyAdmin I can avoid this problem either in the export or import process.

How can I avoid the problem of non-existent tablespaces when I export/import?

**Export server:**

Server version: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server

Protocol version: 10

**Import server:**

Server version: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3

Protocol version: 10

Answer (score 1):

Before importing, removing the text `` /*!50100 TABLESPACE `my_database` */ `` wherever it appears in the exported MySQL file solves the problem.